# Add UI element dynamically on Button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I made a simple Form with a TableLayoutPanel and a button below it.
Is it possible to create another TableLayoutPanel below the one I already have on each button click?
And how can i fill it with data?
I searched for many hours but didn't find anything.

Here is a screenshot of my form, if it helps you:
[image: I want the other tables to appear on the lower half of the split]
I want the other tables to appear on the lower half of the split.
Thanks in advance, Jan

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.  You may want to consider adding the TableLayoutPanels to a FlowLayoutPanel so that they will wrap and scroll automatically.

Just create the control, setup the columns and rows, then add it to some container:

```
TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
// setup "tlp" with your desired properties
tlp.XXX = YYY
// ...
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tlp);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I add the properties like so:
tlp.Width = 200;
tlp.Height = 100;
Why isn't it showing anything for me?

Comment: You need to add Columns and Rows to it...see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137425/table-layout-panel-column-row-count) for some example code.